# Python converting characters to URL encoding

Tags: python, url, encoding

I am trying to convert texts into URLs, but certain characters are not being converted as I'm expecting. For example:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> my_text="City of Liège"
>>> my_url=urllib.parse.quote(my_text,safe='')
>>> my_url
'City%20of%20Li%C3%A8ge'
```

The spaces get converted properly, however, the "è" should get converted into `%E8`, but it is returned as `%C3%A8`. What am I missing ?
I am using Python 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is UTF-8 encoded, and the URL encoded string reflects this.

0xC3A8 is the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode value U+00E8, which is described as "LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH GRAVE".

In order to get the string you are after, you need to let Python know which codepage you're using, like this:

```
my_text=bytes("City of Liège",'cp1252')
```

Comment: So how should I change my code in order to get the desired result ?

Comment: Try replacing the assignment with this and see what happens: 

my_text = "City of Liège".decode('utf-8')

Comment: I don't have the same version of python as you do, so I can't do the urllib.parse.quote() step to verify that it works.  Sorry about that.

But what I can do is see that the string prints as u'City of Li\xe8ge', which looks more like what you're after.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`. I am using Python 3.6.1

Comment: Based on your comment, I needed to convert text encoding to into `cp1252`, like this: `my_text=bytes("City of Liège",'cp1252')`. If you change your answer to incorporate this, I will accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working!  I've updated my answer with your code snippet.  Let me know if you think I should rephrase it.